# Future date trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, constraints

I have a table, and i am unable to have a constraint which checks between first date and sysdate, so i am trying to use a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_before_dob_insert
( BEFORE INSERT 
  on CONS
  FOR EACH ROW 
    IF(:new.Dob > sysdate) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Date of DOB can not be future date.');
    END IF;
END;
)
/
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword

Im really stuck! Please help!

Comment: This is the error im getting                                       ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword

Comment: Do you really need a trigger? Why not a basic check constraint?

Comment: If i use a basic check constraint, it would need to be updated daily for todays date

Comment: @jarlh - looks like Oracle doesn't allow you to access `sysdate` or any other temporally non-deterministic function in check constraints.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I see. Well, that explains the need of a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_before_dob_insert
 BEFORE INSERT 
  on CONS
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF(:new.Dob > sysdate) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Date of DOB can not be future date.');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: () are not required in creating the trigger. If you like my answer, please accept it. thanks.